# Oшибка при переходе с http на https

Tags: nginx, ruby, ssl

Здравствуйте. Есть сайт на Nginx . Была попытка перейти на HTTPS  - SSL  сертификат Let's Ecrypt. Переходом со стороны  сервера Nginx занималась поддержка хостинга. Говорят что вроде как установили, но Ruby-приложение  сайта мешает переходу на защищенное соединение.- сайт не стал доступен по https (вместо этого идет перенаправление на ISPmanager)- похоже переадресация на панель управления задана. Может кто сталкивался с подобной ситуацией , посоветуйте действительно однозначно проблема в Ruby( просто не понятно почему приложение делает редирект на панель управления по защищенному протоколу) или есть вариант что проблема на сервере ? В Ruby  все изменения для работы по https вроде внесены.

Спасибо что откликнулись . Проверили по openssl s_client получили это
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 CN = 
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN =

### verify return:1

Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=

### i:/CN=

Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIBqTCCARICCQCTd+BdHs3LFjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADAZMRcwFQYDVQQDEw45
MS4yMzkuMjMyLjE4MjAeFw0xNTEyMTYxNDE5MTNaFw0yNTEyMTMxNDE5MTNaMBkx
FzAVBgNVBAMTDjkxLjIzOS4yMzIuMTgyMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCB
iQ
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=

### issuer=/CN=

### No client certificate CA names sent

### SSL handshake has read 976 bytes and written 421 bytes

New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 1024 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: FAFF1A97B82E347DC649D1DC68D2F73306A75AFF2D42D2CA90B48EA4390460B9
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 37705F4DDF26F226141B0D89050B8088B03320EEFBC9253969C6E47A2F0FFEF0A7FC9EA7EF75C2A5EBFA1AD88EA97D2B
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 09 8e bc 0c 46 01 6d f7-1b ab eb 03 9f 87 74 99   ....F.m.......t.
    0010 - 7c 8d 66 9e 24 98 29 fb-75 85 f8 e7 e0 fb 53 f2   |.f.$.).u.....S.
    0020 - f9 80 ee 3d bf 66 4a 3e-d8 f9 36 97 5b 76 7b e7   ...=.fJ>..6.[v{.
    0030 - 7a 50 7c a5 4c b2 a3 62-80 ee f2 29 5e ab 28 ad   zP|.L..b...)^.(.
    0040 - b2 d6 a2 80 a9 bc 7a 91-c1 eb 82 25 81 d2 df 4e   ......z....%...N
    0050 - 8e cd bd 24 f7 36 a1 a7-2d 30 7b 80 cb 42 ef 5d   ...$.6..-0{..B.]
    0060 - 0d f8 25 e9 43 87 20 b8-84 3e 45 82 bf 65 be 48   ..%.C. ..>E..e.H
    0070 - ae 3b a5 e7 a2 c3 b0 92-c4 e8 c6 f2 93 ce 60 fa   .;............`.
    0080 - 18 fc cc dd c0 35 4b e3-74 86 1c 9e 21 f8 6d 2c   .....5K.t...!.m,
    0090 - cc 31 82 39 e6 39 7a bc-ca 2d 0d 26 45 02 35 77   .1.9.9z..-.&E.5w
    00a0 - b1 e3 8e 23 a6 94 b0 50-ff c4 cf d2 d7 46 0b 37   ...#...P.....F.7

```
Start Time: 1488016281
Timeout   : 300 (sec)
```

### Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)

closed

Comment: Как вы проверяли? Посмотрите на заголовки браузера. Проверьте возможность соединения через SSL через `openssl s_client -connect адрес_сервера:порт`. Порт скорее всего 443. Там же посмотрите, правильные-ли сертификаты отдает сервер.

Comment: *сайт не стал доступен по https (вместо этого идет перенаправление на ISPmanager)* -- если это не только ваш ISPmanager, то поддержка таки накосячила. Ruby должно быть по большей части до фонаря, ведь nginx делает SSL termination и дальнейшее соединение идёт в пределах машины просто по HTTP, Ruby-приложение может даже не заметить разницы. Ну, это всё "скорее всего". Изучите этот вариант.